# Stop timer at zero

Tags: javascript, function, clearinterval

I am trying to get my countdown to stop at zero however it resets rather than stops.

I've added a conditional statement at the end of the runTimer function but nothing happens. It just resets.

I'm going off of an exercise where it counts up. I'm modifying it a bit and having it countdown.

```
function runTimer() {
    let currentTime = leadingZero(timer[1]) + ":" + leadingZero(timer[2]);
    theTimer.innerHTML = currentTime;
    timer[3]--;

    timer[0] = Math.floor((timer[3]/100)/60); //minutes
    timer[1] = Math.floor((timer[3]/100) - (timer[0] * 60)); //seconds
    timer[2] = Math.floor(timer[3] - (timer[1] * 100) - (timer[0] * 6000)); //hundredths

    if (currentTime = 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

}
```

I expected it to stop at zero but it just resets back to 59:00... and I want it to stop at 00:00.

Comment: Then why use an interval? Also, `=` and `==` (preferably `===`) are different things.

Comment: you are setting current time, not comparing it, also you compare a string against an int

Comment: `currentTime` looks like formatted output, and thus shouldn't be used for internal comparisons. It looks like what you want is `if (timer[3] == 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points.

1) As already mentioned, your if clause will not work because you are using "=" (a single equal sign). A single equal sign in JavaScript does *assign* values, not *compare* values. You however want to compare values and need to use double or triple equals.

2) Even if you change that, `currentTime` will probably never evaluate to zero, since you have assigned a string to `currentTime` before. So even if currentTime is `"00:00"`, the string will not evaluate to 0 (see image)

[image]

I guess you more want to do something like this:

```
if (timer[2] === 0 && timer [1] === 0 && timer[0] === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Or most probably this will suffice:

```
if (timer[3] <= 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: Cool. I was able to stop the time however I'm now at the point where the timer stops at 00:01. Not sure how to override that "00:01".

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Reason is you're decreasing timer[3] *before* you do the check of `currentTime`. Best thing to do is moving the line `timer[3]--;` *after* `if (timer[3] <= 0) {...}` So that if *first* checks if the timer is at zero and - if timer is not at zero - decreases the timer. This way you should actually get to see "00:00".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this part:

`if (currentTime = 0)`

Since you're checking if the value is 0, you don't want to *assign* a value of `0`, instead you want to compare `currentTime` with `0`. This is done with the `===` operator. So to summarize:

`=` is to *assign* a value to a variable. ( left is variable and right is the assignment)

`==` or `===` is to compare the two values.([Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript))

Your line should be:

`if (currentTime == 0)`

Hope it helped. :)

Comment: There are more issues than that. While this is certainly *part* of the problem, it goes a bit beyond that.